# How to write Mediawiki plugin which will add html before first heading - what hook should be used?

Tags: mediawiki

I want to put some information near page heading on Mediawiki page in floating box but cannot find what hook should be used to do it.

```
<!-- Question is: How to inject code here? -->
<!-- firstHeading -->
<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Strona główna</h1>
<!-- /firstHeading -->
```

Could you help with this I am not know what hook or specific method should be used to modify Mediawiki page?

Comment: What does it mean "near"? Do you want to add site notice?

Comment: Not I want render some custom html code floating to heading. I will see what is possible with site notice soon.

Comment: Site notice won't help then. It's for adding site notices.

Comment: I've reworked my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a straightforward way to do it, but it's somewhat achievable.

1. You could set a [[MediaWiki:Tagline]] message.  See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=New_York_City&action=view&uselang=qqx) for example.  You may want to use `&uselang=qqx` param to enable such message help.  Tagline allows you to set content near the h1 with ease.
2. You may use client side scripts to inject stuff. This technique is actually used on Wikipedias to achieve this goal. Remember though, that browsers which are not capable to run JavaScript (probably includes googlebot) won't be able to see it.
3. Write an extension, but this is probably an overkill.

There might be other approaches, but I am not aware of them.

Comment: 1. maybe but still need inject javascript. 2. no, google should scan it. 3. yes, want do this since programmer!